# How can I colour the maximum and minimum value for each column using kable in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have the following table in RMarkdown:

[image]

which I did using the following code:

```
kable(taula_decils_CNAE,
      booktabs=TRUE,
      digits=2,
      format.args = list(big.mark="."),
      col.names=c("Grups de despesa", "1r decil", "2n decil", "3r decil", "4t decil", "5è decil", "6è decil", "7è decil", "8è decil", "9è decil", "10è decil"),
      linesep = "" ,
      caption="Pes (%) de cada grup de despesa sobre la despesa monetària, per decils de renda") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"), bootstrap_options = c("condensed"), position="center") %>% 
  column_spec(1, width="4cm") %>%
  column_spec(2:10, width="2cm") %>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T)
```

How can I colour with red, for instance, the maximum value of each column? And the minimum value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr::mutate and across`.
And a couple of other tweaks:

- % is a special character in Latex so this should have a double backslash in front to protect it.
- add `escape = FALSE` to the kbl call to escape special characters when rendering to pdf.

Updated in response to OP's request to highlight minimum values as well: achieve with nested `ifelse` functions.

````
---
title: "Highlight max and min values by colours for each column"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)

```

```
{r results='asis'}


mtcars |> 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~cell_spec(.x, color = ifelse(.x == max(.x), "red", ifelse(.x == min(.x), "green", "black"))))) |>                          
  kbl(booktabs=TRUE,
      digits=2,
      format.args = list(big.mark="."),
      linesep = "" ,
      caption="Pes (\\%) de cada grup de despesa sobre la despesa monetària, per decils de renda",
      escape = FALSE) |> 
  kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"), bootstrap_options = c("condensed"), position="center") |>
  column_spec(1, width="4cm") |> 
  row_spec(0, bold = T)
```
````

[I find this a useful resource for kableExtra tables](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Is there any wat to add minimum as well?

Comment: Yes there is, please see updated answer.